# How to add target="_blank" into a document.write?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I am doing this on chrome dev tools. The error message I am getting is, "Can't open same-window link to "URL"; try target="_blank". I can't figure out how to incorporate that into this Javascript.

```
document.write=function(s){
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var lastScript = scripts[scripts.length-1];
    lastScript.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", s);
    }
    var txt = "Let's Start";

    document.write("<p>Link: " + txt.link("beginning.html") , "_blank" + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing that to this line:

```
document.write("<p>Link: " + txt.link("beginning.html") , "_blank" + "</p>");
```

to

```
document.write("<p>Link: " + txt.link("beginning.html") + " _blank" +  "</p>");
```

Strictly a guess as we assume .link() is returning a string (?)

Answer (score 0):

First: **The link() method is not standard, and may not work as expected in all browsers.**

Second: There is no correct way to do it with String object https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_link.asp

Third:

```
var link = "<a href='beginning.html' target='_blank'>Let's Start</a>";
document.write("<p>Link: " + link + "</p>");
```